# How to split URL in reactjs/nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The full URl is `/search-results?query=home+floor&categories=All+Categories`. I want to split it into two parts like this -
`/search-results` and `query=home+floor&categories=All+Categories`. I need the second part of the url. How can I do this in reactjs/nextjs or in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) to achieve this:

```
var path = window.location.pathname; //should be /search-result
var queryString = substr(window.location.search, 1); //should be  query=home+floor&categories=All+Categories
```

EDIT: In Next.js you can also use [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) (in a React component)

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

// in component
const router = useRouter();
const {pathname, query} = router; //pathname and query are what you are looking for.
```

Comment: If I want to access like this, it returns me an object as the query part is made of query +  category. I need to access the "query=home+floor&categories=All+Categories" part inside the getServerSideProps. So that I can append the part with the baseUrl and can fetch the data from the server.

Comment: For access in `getServerSideProps` take a look at the [docs for the `context` argument](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) - `context.params` and `context.query` should be enough for you, otherwise dig into `context.req`

Answer (score 2):

You can simple use the `.split()` function on the string, splitting by the "?"-character:

```js
let uri = "/search-results?query=home+floor&categories=All+Categories";

let parts = uri.split("?");

let path = parts[0]; // "/search-results"
let query = parts[1]; // "query=home+floor&categories=All+Categories"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

When working with locations in next.js applications, it's typically best to use the built-in router hook.
While relying on `window` would work for client-side rendering, you might run into problems when next.js is rendering something on the server-side.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function YourComponent() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const parts = router.asPath.split('?')
  // ...
}
```

This would give you an array in the paths variable where `paths[0]` is `/search-results` and `paths[1]` contains your query.
Depending on your use-case it might, however, be better to just use `router.query`, which gives you the parsed query part.

The [documentation for next/router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) is actually pretty good.

Comment: thank you. But I need to access the query part inside the getServerSideProps function. And hooks can't be accessed there.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, you'd really have to either split the `context.resolvedUrl` or use the `context.query` property.

Comment: Thank you. Context.resolvedUrl solved my problem.